# Can't find MvxActivity in MvvmCross 6.0

Tags: c#, visual-studio, mvvmcross

I'm upgrading from MvvMCross 5.7 to 6.0.0.

The class MvxActivity was before under `MvvmCross.Droid.Views`
But now the docs says:

> MvvmCross.Platform namespace is now MvvmCross.
>
> MvvmCross.Platform.{Platform}.Platform is now MvvmCross.Platforms.{Platform}.Base.

The problem is that I can't find a Platform or Platforms namespace under MvvMcross so I can't reach to MvvmCross.Platform.Android.Platform.

And the "[migration guide](https://www.mvvmcross.com/documentation/upgrading/upgrade-to-mvvmcross-60)" isn't helping.

I also have under MvvmCross, the namespaces Binding and Core but the docs says that they have been removed.

> With MvvmCross 6 there are some changes to the NuGet packages. The following packages are obsolete and included in the main MvvmCross package:
>
> MvvmCross.Core
>
> MvvmCross.Platform
>
> MvvmCross.Binding

Dou you have any idea of whats happening here?

I'm under VS2017

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally managed how to do this.

I created other project with a different name (Because of temps files of VS are 10/10)

And after that I added all the files from my old project manually

Answer (score 1):

MvxActivity is in

```
MvvmCross.Platforms.Android.Views
```

As seen here, https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross/blob/e37c07f7908a86241713ea4aac384b2f2f0361bf/MvvmCross/Platforms/Android/Views/MvxActivity.cs
Your Bindings should be

```
MvvmCross.Platforms.{Platform}.Binding
```

Be careful with that (s) Platform(s)

Comment: My problem is that MvvmCross tells me that there isn't a Platform/Platforms under MvvmCross

Comment: Are you sure everything upgraded to 6.0? Clean/restart visual studio?

Comment: Yeah, the only mvvmcross nuget package I have installed now, Is the MvvmCross version 6.0